# GCP Monitoring: Is it possible to set up the monitor with a time range specifically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, policies, network-monitoring

I want to set up a monitor just at night as its when we really need the alert monitoring, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to enable|disable or snooze [Alerting](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts) during specific periods.

[Snoozing](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/manage-snooze) alerts appears (!?) to be currently only possible through Cloud Console which may be restrictive and don't appear to support recurring (everyday) schedules.

I think another alternative, is to disable alerts during the day and re-enable them overnight. You can use the API's [`projects.alertPolicies.Patch`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies/patch) method or [`gcloud alpha monitoring policies update`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/monitoring/policies/update)

```bash
# During the day
gcloud alpha monitoring policies update ${POLICY} \
--no-enabled \
--project=${PROJECT}

# During the night
gcloud alpha monitoring policies update ${POLICY} \
--enabled \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Rather than remembering to do this, you could use cron or e.g. [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) to schedule the switch.